# How to measure temperature using a sensor and Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I am new to IoT, and I want to measure the temperature of a motor and record the data to a server. Since I have experience in back-end programming, I know how to push data to a server from a Pi, but my problem is how to properly measure temperature of a motor (of a floor cleaning machine).
I found some sensors (LM35DZ) which will measure temperature, but I am building a hardware which should work for 10 hours a day and it should be stable. So could you suggest what the proper sensor and the way to do it is?

Comment: Hi Rinas can you elaborate a bit more about the environment the sensor will be deployed in and the frequency and precision it should  have to measure and report data?

Comment: Since a pi doesn't have an ADC you probably want a sensor with a digital output.  However, a floor cleaning machine sounds like something that is only plugged in while in use, and a pi is an extremely bad choice for something that looses power unpredictably - something that doesn't depend on an SD card or have a lengthy boot time would be a better fit, for example an ESP8266, or even a Linux "router" chip that runs from an SPI flash that can be made truly read only, unlike a card (though typically still boots slowly).

Comment: Voting for close in two reasons: 1) question is better fit in https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com or https://electronics.stackexchange.com and 2) recommending things appears off-topic all around SE.

Comment: If you're asking about a Pi, this would be better on the other site. DS18B20 would be my suggestion, but it might be upset by electrical noise from the motor. If you're asking about which MCU, maybe on-topic here. Needs a bit more data - but I don't think the 'shopping req' applies, this is a how to.

Comment: Take a look here: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-11-ds18b20-temperature-sensing/hardware if this is the route you want to go.

Answer (score 4):

10 hours, and a few sensors, then the Raspberry Pi is overkill. A arduino is a more fitting device.

And take a look at one-wire temp sensors like DS18B20 then you have a digital output from the temp sensor.

And if you want to push the data over WiFi, then is ESP8266 or eq a nice fit to your project.